# how to re-calculate the dependent variable of an R model

Tags: formula

result~1+Speed+Reltailsize+tailcontrst+relsvl:Speed+Reltailsize:Speed+Reltailsize:relsvl+strategy:relsvl+tailcontrst:Reltailsize

I have fitted it using
require(MASS)
polr(result~1+Speed+Reltailsize+tailcontrst+relsvl:Speed+Reltailsize:Speed+Reltailsize:relsvl+strategy:relsvl+tailcontrst:Reltailsize, data=results)

and got the coefficients:
my question now is how do I do now to re calculate values of "result" substituting the values of the factors?

I have two specific doubt about that, 
1) what do I substitute ":" for?  Maybe "/" ?
2) Do i need to re use a probit link function? how do I do this?

Comment: Dear all, I advanced in my problem. : cannot be substituted by / because it means that the factor vectors should be casewise multiplied (Venables & Ripley, 2002).

Answer (score 0):

I advanced in my problem. : cannot be substituted by / because it means that the factor vectors should be casewise multiplied (Venables & Ripley, 2002).
still dont know how to do an ordered probit transformation with values 1,2 and 3.
cheers
Agus

Answer (score 0):

I advanced more. Now i fit the model using multinom from nnet package and use predict.nnet to get the predicted values from a dataframe with real data.

```
M=multinom(result~1+Speed+relsvl, data=results)
summary(M)

require(nnet)
d=predict (M, realdata)
```

Cheers